# Jquery get parent id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pull a ul's id after the user clicks on a li's item...

This is my jquery

```
$('.mitm').click(function () {
    var itmlvl = $(this).text();
    var itmp = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(itmlvl + " " + itmp);
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="menu_arrow" class="vocab_arrow"></div>
     <ul class="lvldropmnu" id="uvocab">
          <a href="#"><li class="mitm">1</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="mitm">2</li></a>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried a few different combinations using .find() and so forth but no luck, I always get a "undefined" in my alert for the itmp variable.

Comment: The parent of the `li` is the anchor tag. Try `parent('ul')`

Comment: `var itmp = $(this).parents('ul').attr("id");`

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML is incorrect, so you can't expect to get a consistent result. A list can only contain list items, not links.

Put the links inside the list items:

```
<div id="menu_arrow" class="vocab_arrow"></div>
     <ul class="lvldropmnu" id="uvocab">
          <li class="mitm"><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li class="mitm"><a href="#">2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

That will also make the list the parent of the list items, so your corrent code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The parent of $(this) is , you need the use

```
var itmp = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
```

or

```
var itmp = $(this).parent('ul').attr("id");
```

or

```
var itmp = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $('.mitm').click(function () {

    var itm = $(this),
        itmlvl = itm.text(),
        itmp = itm.parent().attr("id");
      alert(itmlvl + " " + itmp);
  });

})();


 <ul class="lvldropmnu" id="uvocab">
      <li class="mitm">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="mitm">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

preview : http://plnkr.co/edit/Lv9lNSLr7J6x2ujlTZgP?p=preview